# How to create user like drop-down filters for a custom module in admin side

Tags: 7

Drupal 7 admin panel, when clicked on people, a form with drop-down filters is visible.

[user filters http://www.imagesup.net/?di=914041271981](http://www.imagesup.net/?di=914041271981)

How can we create above filters in our custom modules ?

I have tried goggling, but when searched filter in Drupal, it returns text filters which replaces text.

I have a custom module in which list of items are show, I want to filter items based on different fields.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks !!

Comment: Why can't you try `Views` module

Comment: can we use _views_ module with custom tables ? I've create module, declared hook_menu, a form which shows list from table using select query.

Comment: You can, but for that you have expose your table/data to views using hooks. But instead of custom tables why can't use Drupal features like node/entity api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have 2 options:

1. [Declare your custom tables with Views](http://mydons.com/how-to-expose-custom-module-table-to-views-in-drupal/). This can be tricky, and take some trial and error, but gives more flexibility going forward.
2. Declare a custom page in your module (using [hook_menu](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7)). Then just build a form with the search options you want and build a query. See the [Examples modules](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples) if you're not sure how to build a page.